# How to access the members of a struct within a struct via a double pointer?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

As part of a school assignment, I am given a structure with a double pointer to another structure inside it. I will need to be able to access the members of the nested structure within a function, but am having no luck doing so.

Here is the code I have been given

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*Given code, do not change */

typedef struct
{
    char* ID;
    char* PassWord;
}Account, *pAccount, **ppAccount;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int numAccounts;
    ppAccount accounts;
}FleaBay,*pFleaBay;

void FleaBayInit(pFleaBay);             /* Initialise the FleaBay instance */

int main(void)
{

    FleaBay e;
    FleaBayInit(&e); /* Call to the function */

    return 0;
}
/* end of given code */
```

Here is my attempt:

```
void FleaBayInit(FleaBay *pFleaBay){ /* Initialise the FleaBay instance */
    Account ac1 = {"test1", "test2"}, *pac1 = &ac1;

    pFleaBay ->numAccounts = 0;
    pFleaBay ->accounts = &pac1;


}
```

I'm having no trouble accessing the member within the non-nested `struct`, but I cannot figure out how to access the members of the nested `Account` structure. Thought that maybe I would need to create an `Account` object first, point to it, and assign the value of the pointer to the `accounts` member within `pFleaBay`, but when I test with `printf("%s",pFleaBay->accounts);`, I get some random characters.

Comment: Are there other parts of your program where you `malloc` memory?

Comment: No, not doing malloc anywhere. The other parts of the program aren't relevant.

Comment: It looks like `ppAccount` is meant to be an array.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: @Jason An array of pointers?

Comment: A 2D array (`ppAccount accounts`) doesn't really make sense with a 1D length (`unsigned int numAccounts`).

Comment: @FiddlingBits I think you're thinking of a ragged array.

Comment: @Jason You're right.  This may be a square 2D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the structure

```
typedef struct
{
    char* ID;
    char* PassWord;
}Account, *pAccount, **ppAccount;
```

`ppAccount` is a pointer to a pointer, which is often used to represent a dynamic array of pointers.

In the second structure

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int numAccounts;
    ppAccount accounts;
}FleaBay,*pFleaBay;
```

you have the number of the accounts, which would be the number of the elements in the dynamic array.  So, in your code you could access one of the accounts using the syntax `pFleaBay->accounts[n]`.  This means that you would want to allocate an array of pointers in your function either using `malloc` or `calloc`.

```
pFleaBay->accounts = calloc(pFleaBay->numAccounts, sizeof(pAccount));
```

Then you can allocate each of the accounts.

Answer (score 4):

In your `FleaBayInit()`, `ac1` is a *local variable*, and `pac1` is initialized as a pointer to `ac1`.  As a local variable, `ac1`'s lifetime is limited to one function call.  After the function returns, `ac1` no longer exists, and any pointer that points to it becomes invalid.

Moreover, `FleaBay.accounts` is an `Account **`, but you try to assign an `Account *` to it (`pac1`).  Not only does that pointer become invalid when the function returns, it isn't even the correct type.  This is actually odd; I don't see any reason why `FleaBay.accounts` should not be simply an `Account *`.

---

**Edited to add:**

On second thought, `FleaBay.accounts` could be an `Account **` because it is meant to point to a dynamic array of `Account *`, as opposed to a dynamic array of `Account`.  That would offer some advantages, particularly if `Account` objects must be independent of `FleaBay`s.

In that case, the simplest way to initialize a `FleaBay` would probably be this:

```
void FleaBayInit(FleaBay *pFleaBay){ /* Initialise the FleaBay instance */
    pFleaBay->numAccounts = 0;
    pFleaBay->accounts = NULL;
}
```

Whether that is actually appropriate, however, depends on how you intend to implement other code that manipulates `FleaBay`s -- especially code that adds or removes accounts.

---